# Pass a changable named range as formula argument

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a formula that checks data on another sheet that is part of a set of sheets that are calendars for given years (2019, 2020,...).

In this formula I check the number of workingdays like this:

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A28;EOMONTH(A28;0);INDIRECT(B28& "!B58:D73"))
```

where **B28** is the year I want to check.

No I need a small change as I have a named range **Holidays_Vacations_yyyy** where **yyyy** is the year. This way the formula should be something like

```
=NETWORKDAYS(A28;EOMONTH(A28;0);INDIRECT("Holidays_Vacations_" & B28))
```

This way, when B28 is 2019, the formula should check named range **Holidays_Vacations_2019**.
But it just gives a #VALUE! error. I must be tired because I cannot find a solution. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

PS: In Portugal, Excel uses semicolon instead of comas as field separator.

Comment: is the value in B28 actually `2019` or is it a date that is formatted to show the year?

Comment: Do you have something included in that named range that isn't a date/number? That would cause a #VALUE error.

Comment: Hi again. I must apologise. I am ideed tired. I missed interely the INDIRECT formula on my sheet but just couldn't see it before this break to ask help. It is working correctly after adding it. Thank you @Scott Craner. Answering your question, yes it is the number of the year (=YEAR(A28)). I feel so embarressed.

Comment: Thank you @Rory The problem was right before my eyes, I missed interely the INDIRECT formula. Adding it solved the problem, Just not sure if I delete the question or keep it for someone looking for assistance with a similar (real) problem!